# Can't find and read .csv file

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I recently brought my code from Jupyter into VSCode. I fixed up some problems with my imports, but now I can't find a .csv file. The code and .csv file are saved in the same folder. My code is:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('emailss.csv', names=['Email', 'Amiability'])
```

After running the program, it says,

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'emailss.csv'
```

What's going on here? How can I fix it? It was working perfectly in Jupyter.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Your working directory does not contain the file.

Comment: It does. Both my Python file and my .csv file are in the same folder.

Comment: The working directory does not need to be the directory where your Python script is located...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where are you running the code from? Is the CSV file in the same directory as your python file, if yes is the console path the same as the python script and the CSV file?

Comment: What do you mean, CSV file in the same console path as Python Script?

Comment: When you run the command to start you're python script checks the current directory of you're console, it has to be the same as the folder where you have the python script and the CSV file

Answer (score 1):

Check with `os.getcwd()` that your current working directory matches with the file path